# Rewrite javascript project in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new web development and thought of learning Angular by creating a simple javascript project in Angular.
This is an udemy project developed in javascript using MVC Pattern
[image]

Here the project is divided in the 3 parts :

Search
Recipe
ShoppingList

once user enter some text in search bar and press search the data will be populated in the left side as shown in image.

I created two components in Angular one is SearchComponent and another result component. I kept Search in the header and result component in the body.I have created one service class called Recipe to get the data from API using HTTPClient.

I am calling the API when I press search button and saving the data in Recipes variable but how to pass that data in resultcomponent.

I got basic doubt Is it correct to create two components when we not routing to another page?

What is the correct way to handle this scenario as we are not navigating how I can populate the resultcomponent once service have Recipe variable with data?

Thanks & Regards,

Nagasree.

Comment: Store the search result as observable and subscribe it on result component, then you will get the data whenever the observable value is changed.
Observable is the concept of RxJS

Comment: Hi Derek, Is it right approach to create components to subparts of page?

Comment: Yeah, now it is mainly separated into two parts (header & body) and they are connected with service. It's normal Angular structure.
And one of the most important is observable on angular and using angular, you can sync the data with api.
This link will help you. https://angular.io/guide/observables-in-angular

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your results inside the service as an observable:

```
export class RecipeService{
    results$: Observable<Result[]>;

    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

    search(value:string){
         this.results$ = this.http.get<Result[]>(...value...);
    }
}
```

Call the service from your search component to populate the results observable:

```
export class SearchComponent {
    constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService) {}

    // call from button in template
    search(value:string){
        this.recipeService.search(value);
     }
}
```

Access the results observable from your results component and use async pipe to handle subscribe/unsubscribe:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-results',
  template: '<li *ngFor=“let result of recipeService.results$ | async”>{{ result.name }} </li>'
})
export class ResultsComponent {
    constructor(private recipeService: RecipeService) {}
}
```

Stackblitz showing above: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-recipes?file=src%2Fapp%2Fresults.component.ts

Looking at the screenshot I would use at least 3 components:

- search bar
- results
- selected recipe

Comment: Cannot find a differ supporting object '[object Object]' of type 'object'. NgFor only supports binding to Iterables such as Arrays. I am getting this error once I changed the code as you specified.I have searched in google they said use async but I already using async as you mentioned

Comment: Should work as recipe$ is an observable array which gets transformed into an array via the async pipe. Try temporarily putting ‘this.result$.subscribe(console.log);’ in the constructor body of the service and see if it logs a list.

Comment: Also try using the updated line of code for initializing recipe$ in the service.

Comment: I have checked using console.log() it is getting the data but even after initializing also getting same error.

Comment: Very likely your http service is not returning data in the correct list/array format. Here is a working stackblitz based on the advice above but it uses `of` operator to return the array of recipes rather than calling an http service (which I don't have): https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-recipes?file=src%2Fapp%2Fresults.component.ts

Comment: Otherwise what is the actual output of the console.log?

Comment: "https://forkify-api.herokuapp.com/api/search?&q='Pizza'" this is the API I am using

Comment: output of console.log  is array of recipes.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-recipes-l3bjvk?file=src/app/recipe.service.ts

Comment: I did modifications to the app you shared and I am getting the same exception what I mentioned.Could you please look into it once

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221731/discussion-between-nagasree-and-wlf).

Comment: Thank you I understood what I did wrong and I am able to show the results. I am glad that my first step got successful